# Flow hangs when IdempotentReceiverInterceptor discards the message(after 4-th message)

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have following flow:

```
    return flow -> flow.channel(inputChannel())
             ... 
            .gateway(childFlow, addMyInterceptor(str)); // by name
}


Consumer<GatewayEndpointSpec> addMyInterceptor(String objectIdHeader) {
    return endpointSpec -> endpointSpec.advice(addMyInterceptorInternal(objectIdHeader))
            .errorChannel(errorChannel());
}

default IdempotentReceiverInterceptor addMyInterceptorInternal(String header) {
    MessageProcessor<String> headerSelector = message -> headerExpression(header).apply(message);
    var interceptor = new IdempotentReceiverInterceptor(new MetadataStoreSelector(headerSelector, idempotencyStore()));
    interceptor.setDiscardChannel(idempotentDiscardChannel());
    return interceptor;
}
```

When `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor` encounters that message is duplicated - I see that application hangs on after 4-th duplicated message. I understand that it is because gateway expected response(like here: [PubSubInboundChannelAdapter stops to receive messages after 4th message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625586/pubsubinboundchanneladapter-stops-to-receive-messages-after-4th-message)) but I don't have any ideas how to return result from interceptor.

Could you please explain it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all channels are direct (default) - i.e. no async handoffs in the flow using queue or executor channels, set the gateway's `replyTimeout` to `0` when the flow might not return a reply

Comment: Tried this approach but messages were stopped to reject. Will investigate in more details.

Comment: Rechecked one more time and see that everything is working properly